# Connecting to postgresql from lapis

Tags: postgresql, lua, openresty

I decided to play with lapis - https://github.com/leafo/lapis, but the application drops when I try to query the database (PostgreSQL) with the output:

> 2017/07/01 16:04:26 [error] 31284#0: *8 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: attempt to yield across C-call boundary
>   stack traceback:
>   coroutine 0:
>           [C]: in function 'require'
>           /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/init.lua:15: in function 'serve'
>           content_by_lua(nginx.conf.compiled:22):2: in function , client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"

The code that causes the error:

```
local db = require("lapis.db")
local res = db.query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

config.lua:

```
config({ "development", "production" }, {
    postgres = {
        host = "0.0.0.0",
        port = "5432",
        user = "wars_base",
        password = "12345",
        database = "wars_base"
    }
})
```

The database is running, the table is created, in table 1 there is a record.

What could be the problem?

**Decision**: https://github.com/leafo/lapis/issues/556

Comment: Answer: https://github.com/leafo/lapis/issues/556

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the right [server IP](https://github.com/leafo/lapis/blob/master/docs/database.md#postgresql) in the `host` parameter.

The IP you have specified `0.0.0.0` is not a valid one, and normally it is used when you specify a listen address, with the meaning of "every address".

Usually you can use the '127.0.0.1' address during development.